# Default NTFS mount (R, R/W) of Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ntfs, ntfs-3g

What is the default mounting for an NTFS drive in Raspbian Jessie?

In Raspbian Wheezy, the default was read-only, and to get read/write, you had to upgrade to `ntfs-3g` and modify the fstab file.  [See my notes here.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/raspberry-pi-and-read-write-on-ntfs-with-raspbian-5-5-2015)  Raspbian Jessie includes `ntfs-3g` by default, and seems to mount the drive read/write automatically, but I am not sure.  For example, I can create a blank file and delete a folder, but not create a new folder using the File Manager GUI program.

Alternatively, how can I determine on my system if a drive is mounted read-only or read-write?

Currently, I'm working with a Raspberry Pi B+.  I tried looking up the Debian side of things and found what look like release notes, but I don't think the information I'm looking for is there:

- [Package: ntfs-config (1.0.1-11 and others)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/admin/ntfs-config)
- [Package: ntfs-3g (1:2014.2.15AR.2-1+deb8u2)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ntfs-3g)

Answer (score 0):

Install `ntfsprogs`

```
apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

identify your usb

```
fdisk -l
```

For example usb  = sdc1

To mount your usb read/write type the following command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdc1
```